# C++ static lib pdb is not merged to DLL pdb

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, static-linking, pdb-files

I am using visual studio 2008.

I have a C# .exe file A.exe which uses C++ DLL B.dll. B.dll statically links to C++ lib C.lib which has a C.pdb file when compile.

I understand that B.pdb should contain all debug information from C.pdb.

Now A.exe and B.dll and B.pdb are in same directory when I debug. I can step into B.dll code, but can't step into C.lib code because visual studio says debug information is not loaded.

They are all debug build. I have carefully checked compile/link settings but can't see problem.

Comment: My psychic debugger says that B is actually a mixed-mode assembly created with a C++/CLI project.  And that you have trouble because you cannot single-step from managed code into native code, a breakpoint in the native code is required.  And that you forgot to enable unmanaged code debugging in your C# project.

Comment: @HansPassant Seems your answer is perfectly right. Do you want to post it as answer?

Comment: Too many guesses, fix your question first.

Comment: If you've checked everything else out, try shutting Visual Studio down, clearing out all visual studio generated files (.vs folder, .suo and .user files, bin folder, obj folder). Recompile and try again. I've not looked to into the root cause, but as with many other debugger problems I've seen, this fixed the problem for me today after nothing else did the trick. - Visual Studio 2015 (14.0) with VS 2013 C# project using VS 2013 C++/cli project dependent on a set of unmanaged C++11 libraries.